# Checking the value of Macro

Tags: macros, erlang

Let's say one file is compiled and is in running mode and it is using some macro.Is there any way to check what value of the macro that is being used by the file.

eg if the file contains

```
-define(TIMEOUT,200).
```

From terminal how can i check what TIMEOUT definition is being used by the file.

Why I want is because suppose file is in running mode and i changed the macro definition in between and forgot to compile the file. I want to confirm what defintion it is taking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros do not survive even the earliest stages of the compilation as the preprocessor substitutes them immediately in the source. You will have to define and export a separate function to see their values, something like:

```
macro_values() ->
  [{'TIMEOUT',?TIMEOUT},...].
```

You can then call this from the shell and get the values that were substituted.